# React Native opening iOS dial app not working

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get the native dial app to open in iOS. All the options I have tried are below:

```
onPress={() => {Linking.openURL(Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'tel:*xxxx' : 'tel://*xxxx')}}
onPress={() => {Linking.openURL(Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'tel:*xxxx' : 'telprompt:*xxxx')}}
onPress={() => {Linking.openURL('tel:*xxxx')}}
```

I am wondering if anyone has another option that might work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: A `tel:xxxxx` url will work on iOS. You can't start the number with * though.

Comment: why you have * before your telephone number?

Comment: Also telprompt need `//` if I am not wrong...